# Extracting an attribute value with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, parsing, attributes, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the content of a single "value" attribute in a specific "input" tag on a webpage. I use the following code:

```
import urllib
f = urllib.urlopen("http://58.68.130.147")
s = f.read()
f.close()

from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup
soup = BeautifulStoneSoup(s)

inputTag = soup.findAll(attrs={"name" : "stainfo"})

output = inputTag['value']

print str(output)
```

I get `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`

Even though, from the Beautifulsoup documentation, I understand that strings should not be a problem here... but I am no specialist, and I may have misunderstood.

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 268, accepted):

`.find_all()` returns list of all found elements, so:

```
input_tag = soup.find_all(attrs={"name" : "stainfo"})
```

`input_tag` is a list (probably containing only one element). Depending on what you want exactly you either should do:

```
output = input_tag[0]['value']
```

or use `.find()` method which returns only one (first) found element:

```
input_tag = soup.find(attrs={"name": "stainfo"})
output = input_tag['value']
```

Comment: Great stuff! Thanks. now i have a question about parsing the output which i a long bunch of non-ASCII chars but I will ask this in a separate question.

Comment: shouldn't the 'value' be accessed as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616659/extracting-value-in-beautifulsoup . What makes the above code work in this case? I thought you would have to access the value by doing `output = inputTag[0].contents`

Comment: @Seth - no, because he is looking for input-tag's attrib 'value', and .contents returns the text encapsulated by the tag (<span>I am .contents</span>) -- (just replying now because I had to double check what was going on; figure someone else may benefit)

Comment: great answer.  however, I would use `inputTag[0].get('value')`  instead of `inputTag[0]['value']` to prevent none pointer in case the tag as no value attribute

Comment: what about to links which are not directly linked to homepage of visiting website, How to get all links whether linked to webpage directly or indirectly.

Comment: How to find a tag that has a given attribute but it's value is irrelevant/unknown?

Answer (score 53):

In `Python 3.x`, simply use `get(attr_name)` on your tag object that you get using `find_all`:

```
xmlData = None

with open('conf//test1.xml', 'r') as xmlFile:
    xmlData = xmlFile.read()

xmlDecoded = xmlData

xmlSoup = BeautifulSoup(xmlData, 'html.parser')

repElemList = xmlSoup.find_all('repeatingelement')

for repElem in repElemList:
    print("Processing repElem...")
    repElemID = repElem.get('id')
    repElemName = repElem.get('name')

    print("Attribute id = %s" % repElemID)
    print("Attribute name = %s" % repElemName)
```

against XML file `conf//test1.xml` that looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
    <singleElement>
        <subElementX>XYZ</subElementX>
    </singleElement>
    <repeatingElement id="11" name="Joe"/>
    <repeatingElement id="12" name="Mary"/>
</root>
```

prints:

```
Processing repElem...
Attribute id = 11
Attribute name = Joe
Processing repElem...
Attribute id = 12
Attribute name = Mary
```

Comment: Would you mind if I edit this to follow PEP 8 and use the more modern string formatting methods?

Comment: That's fine, go for it

Answer (score 23):

For me:

```html
<input id="color" value="Blue"/>
```

This can be fetched by below snippet.

```python
page = requests.get("https://www.abcd.com")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
colorName = soup.find(id='color')
print(colorName['value'])
```

Comment: Where do you define `color`?

Comment: I guess, he forgot to use `colorName['value']` instead of `color['value']`.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to retrieve multiple values of attributes from the source above, you can use `findAll` and a list comprehension to get everything you need:

```
import urllib
f = urllib.urlopen("http://58.68.130.147")
s = f.read()
f.close()

from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup
soup = BeautifulStoneSoup(s)

inputTags = soup.findAll(attrs={"name" : "stainfo"})
### You may be able to do findAll("input", attrs={"name" : "stainfo"})

output = [x["stainfo"] for x in inputTags]

print output
### This will print a list of the values.
```

Answer (score 6):

I would actually suggest you a time saving way to go with this assuming that you know what kind of tags have those attributes.

suppose say a tag xyz has that attritube named "staininfo"..

```
full_tag = soup.findAll("xyz")
```

And i wan't you to understand that full_tag is a list

```
for each_tag in full_tag:
    staininfo_attrb_value = each_tag["staininfo"]
    print staininfo_attrb_value
```

Thus you can get all the attrb values of staininfo for all the tags xyz

Answer (score 6):

you can also use this :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

url = "http://58.68.130.147/"
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
get_details = soup.find_all("input", attrs={"name":"stainfo"})

for val in get_details:
    get_val = val["value"]
    print(get_val)
```

Comment: How does this differ from the much older answers which were already here?

Answer (score 5):

You could try to use the new powerful package called *requests_html*:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()

r = session.get("https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology-54448223")
date = r.html.find('time', first = True) # finding a "tag" called "time"
print(date)  # you will have: <Element 'time' datetime='2020-10-07T11:41:22.000Z'>
# To get the text inside the "datetime" attribute use:
print(date.attrs['datetime']) # you will get '2020-10-07T11:41:22.000Z'
```

Answer (score 4):

I am using this with Beautifulsoup 4.8.1 to get the value of all class attributes of  certain elements:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = "<td class='val1'/><td col='1'/><td class='val2' />"

bsoup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for td in bsoup.find_all('td'):
    if td.has_attr('class'):
        print(td['class'][0])
```

Its important to note that the attribute key retrieves a list even when the attribute has only a single value.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example for how to extract the `href` attrbiutes of all `a` tags:

```
import requests as rq 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = "http://www.cde.ca.gov/ds/sp/ai/"
page = rq.get(url)
html = bs(page.text, 'lxml')

hrefs = html.find_all("a")
all_hrefs = []
for href in hrefs:
    # print(href.get("href"))
    links = href.get("href")
    all_hrefs.append(links)

print(all_hrefs)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try [gazpacho](https://github.com/maxhumber/gazpacho):

Install it using `pip install gazpacho`

Get the HTML and make the `Soup` using:

```py
from gazpacho import get, Soup

soup = Soup(get("http://ip.add.ress.here/"))  # get directly returns the html

inputs = soup.find('input', attrs={'name': 'stainfo'})  # Find all the input tags

if inputs:
    if type(inputs) is list:
        for input in inputs:
             print(input.attr.get('value'))
    else:
         print(inputs.attr.get('value'))
else:
     print('No <input> tag found with the attribute name="stainfo")
```