# Python Regex String Extraction

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm trying to extract two strings from this string using Regular Expressions -

```
'<img src="http://images.efollett.com/books/978/047/012/9780470129296.gif" width="80" height="100" alt="Organic Chemistry I (as Second Language)" />'
```

I want the URL after src and the text after alt (so Organic Chemistry I (as Second Language)) and the url)

I've tried `('<img src=(\w+)" width')`, `('<img src="(\w+)"')` and `('src="(\w+)"\swidth')`, for the url and all return empty.

I've also tried `('alt="(\w+)"')` for the name and again, no luck.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `r'<img[^>]*\ssrc="(.*?)"'` and `r'<img[^>]*\salt="(.*?)"'`.

I don't know if you are dealing with HTML. `[^>]*` is to ensure inside brackets. `\s` is used to avoid some tags like "xxxsrc", and take care of newlines.

Comment: This works but backtracks.  Probably okay for small img tags.  +1 for correctness.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/).

```
import lxml.html

html_string = '<img src="http://images.efollett.com/books/978/047/012/9780470129296.gif" width="80" height="100" alt="Organic Chemistry I (as Second Language)" />'

img = lxml.html.fromstring(html_string)

print "src:", img.get("src")
print "alt:", img.get("alt")
```

**Gives**:

```
src: http://images.efollett.com/books/978/047/012/9780470129296.gif
alt: Organic Chemistry I (as Second Language)
```

Answer (score 2):

Although you should [not be parsing HTML with regexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), I can point out a common error here with regexes, which is your use of `\w`.  That only matches A-Z, a-z, 0-9, and underscores.  Not slashes, not parentheses.  If you are trying to pull data out of attributes, use `"([^"]*)"` or `"(.*?)"`

Comment: two questions- first how else would I extract the information that I want (I'm using Beautiful Soup and the other form of the above is as a BeautifulSoup tag)? Second, what regex can I use to get what I want?

Comment: Oh apologies then, I did not know you were using Beautiful Soup, which *is* an HTML parser!  There are hints in [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612548/extracting-an-attribute-value-with-beautifulsoup).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know python, but may this regular expression helps?

```
<img.*?src="([^"]*)".*?alt="([^"]*)".*?>
```

Comment: This works provided the src comes before the alt.  Also a tip for efficiency: don't use `.*` in the middle of a regex.  `.*?` is more appropriate in this case.

Comment: Thanks, updated. You're right, only if the string is given as described in the question (`alt` after `src` attribute) this regex makes sense.