# How to extract src in img tag with regex?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract an image source url from a HTML img tag.

if html data is like below:

```
<div> My profile <img width='300' height='300' src='http://domain.com/profile.jpg'> </div>
```

or

```
<div> My profile <img width="300" height="300" src="http://domain.com/profile.jpg"> </div>
```

how's the regex in python?

I had tried below:

```
i = re.compile('(?P<src>src=[["[^"]+"][\'[^\']+\']])')
i.search(htmldata)
```

but I got an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Comment: Have you already tried to create regex yourself; that would help

Comment: The above 2 lines of code do not give you that error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Regex String Extraction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384275/python-regex-string-extraction)

Answer (score 10):

[BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#beautiful-soup-documentation) parser is the way to go.

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> s = '''<div> My profile <img width='300' height='300' src='http://domain.com/profile.jpg'> </div>'''
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'html.parser')
>>> img = soup.select('img')
>>> [i['src'] for i in img if  i['src']]
[u'http://domain.com/profile.jpg']
>>>
```

Comment: this is a useful answer but someone please accept the requested edits - the edit queue is apparently full people have wanted to edit this one so much lol.  Remove those '>>>' chars to support copy-paste programmers :P

Answer (score 4):

I adapted your code a little bit. Please take a look:

```
import re

url = """<div> My profile <img width="300" height="300" src="http://domain.com/profile.jpg"> </div>"""
ur11 = """<div> My profile <img width='300' height='300' src='http://domain.com/profile.jpg'> </div>"""

link = re.compile("""src=[\"\'](.+)[\"\']""")

links = link.finditer(url)
for l in links:
    print l.group()
    print l.groups()

links1 = link.finditer(ur11)
for l in links1:
    print l.groups()
```

In `l.groups()` you can find the link.

The output is this:

```
src="http://domain.com/profile.jpg"
('http://domain.com/profile.jpg',)
('http://domain.com/profile.jpg',)
```

finditer() is a generator and allows using a `for in` loop.

**Sources:**

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm

https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html

Comment: it will not work if there are other attributes after src.  and also your group is fails to capture `/:-.` etc. which can be part of the url. here is my pattern. 
`src=[\"\']([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\/\-:]+)[\"\']`

Comment: There is definitely room for improvement. Thanks for your input.