# How can I get an specific id from html code with python?

Tags: python, html, parsing

I've got a lot of html response code, at some part there's this part:

```
</td>
</tr>
    <input id="hiddenloginurl" type="hidden" name="loginurl" value="/sensor.htm?id=10240">
</table>
```

How can I parse the html code and get this id with python? The problem is, at every new api call, the id is changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

> Beautiful Soup provides a few simple methods and Pythonic idioms for navigating, searching, and modifying a parse tree: a toolkit for
>   dissecting a document and extracting what you need. It doesn't take
>   much code to write an application
>
> Beautiful Soup automatically converts incoming documents to Unicode
>   and outgoing documents to UTF-8. You don't have to think about
>   encodings, unless the document doesn't specify an encoding and
>   Beautiful Soup can't autodetect one. Then you just have to specify the
>   original encoding.
>
> Beautiful Soup sits on top of popular Python parsers like lxml and
>   html5lib, allowing you to try out different parsing strategies or
>   trade speed for flexibility.

Also see this similar question: [Extracting an attribute value with beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612548/extracting-an-attribute-value-with-beautifulsoup)

```
inputTag = soup.find(attrs={"name": "stainfo"})
output = inputTag['value']
```