# Implementing Regular expressions in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a code like this.

```
 <td class="check ABCD" rowspan="2"><center><div class="checkbox {{#if checked}}select{{else}}deselect{{/if}}" id="{{id}}" {{data "tool"}

<td class="check" rowspan="2"><center><div class="checkbox {{#if checked}}select{{else}}deselect{{/if}}" id="{{id}}" {{data "tool"}}>
```

And I want to extract only the class and ID name in the above code. I have very little knowledge about using regular expression in python.

How can I extract only the class name & id name(the ones in between "") using regular expression? or is there any better way to do this?.
If yes, please help me finding it :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this have to be done with regex?

Comment: @idjaw Is there any other way to extract it? Other than Regex?

Comment: I don't know if this is part of a much bigger chunk of data. But this definitely looks like HTML, and if you are trying to parse through that, you should use something like [BeautifulSoup](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612548/extracting-an-attribute-value-with-beautifulsoup

  this should help you

Comment: You can convert the dom element into BeautifulStoneSoup object and then get the attribute values

Comment: @idjaw Basically this is the difference  of two similar .stache files. I want to eliminate the unwanted data from this diff.

Anyhow, I will look into BeautifulSoap. Thanks :)

Comment: Obligatory: [You cannot parse XHTML with regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: @NEO-xx Thanks for the help. I will definitely look into it. I didn't know about BeautifulSoap !

Comment: @KarthikHegde: It is **Soup** not **Soap** (some programmers might mix both, though...)

Comment: @idjaw How do I parse using BeautifulSoup if those part of the code is string? I mean if it is stored in .txt file?

Answer (score 2):

Since you asked for a Regex solution in Python, you'll get one:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'^.+?class="([^"]+)".+id="([^"]+)".+?$', re.MULTILINE)
test_str = u"<td class=\"check ABCD\" rowspan=\"2\"><center><div class=\"checkbox {{#if checked}}select{{else}}deselect{{/if}}\" id=\"{{id}}\" {{data \"tool\"}\n<td class=\"check\" rowspan=\"2\"><center><div class=\"checkbox {{#if checked}}select{{else}}deselect{{/if}}\" id=\"{{id}}\" {{data \"tool\"}}>"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

See live example over here: https://regex101.com/r/cG8dC5/1

Nevertheless, as some other users already noted. Regex [isn't ideal for parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) (x)HTML. Better have a look at: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4

Comment: When you advise someone not to parse HTML with regex and post a solution nevertheless, isn't this somewhat lurking for rep ;) ?

Comment: Nope. It's the answer to the question. With an helpful advice. If you ask me: "how to make fire with a lens?" I'll answer you - hold it between the sun and some straw. Nevertheless, it's not the best way. Better use an lighter. 

So I think its a valid answer to his question and as long I told him, that there are better ways, this isn't lurking.

Comment: I like the fire analogy (+1 for that), however I'd have bought him a lighter :)