# Regex required or can BeautifulSoup refine output

Tags: python

If I use the following function I can grab the text and link I need from a website:

```
def get_url_text(url):
    source = requests.get(url)
    plain_text = source.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
    for item_name in soup.findAll('li', {'class': 'ptb2'}):
        print(item_name.string)
        print (item_name.a)

get_url_text('https://www.residentadvisor.net/podcast.aspx')
```

returns:

```
RA.532 Marquis Hawkes
<a href="/podcast-episode.aspx?id=532"><h1>RA.532 Marquis Hawkes</h1></a>
RA.531 Evan Baggs
<a href="/podcast-episode.aspx?id=531"><h1>RA.531 Evan Baggs</h1></a>
RA.530 MCDE vs Jeremy Underground
```

If I only want the href link instead of the tags etc surrounding it do I need to use a regex or is there another method within BeautifulSoup?

Desired output is:

```
RA.532 Marquis Hawkes
https://www.residentadvisor.net/podcast-episode.aspx?id=532
```

for each similar element.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extracting an attribute value with beautifulsoup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612548/extracting-an-attribute-value-with-beautifulsoup)

Comment: @DanielG I looked at the linked post and would not have been able to resolve this scenario using the information it contains.  The answer below from ewcz is very useful.

Comment: `output = inputTag[value]` (where `inputTag=item_name.a`; and `value='href'` in your case)  is very similar to what you were looking for, as described in the first answer of said post. But I'm glad you found an answer and your problem is solved now.

Comment: Thanks for explaining DanielG.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `print(item_name.a['href'])` and (if needed) prepend the prefix `https://www.residentadvisor.net` (since the links in the webpage are used in a form without explicit scheme and netloc part - for example, `/podcast-episode.aspx?id=528`)

Comment: Perfect, I will accept the answer when the system allows. thanks