# How to extract a value in BeautifulSoup too hidden

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

```
[<input class="mail opentip" 
        data-original-title="Your temporary Email address" 
        data-placement="bottom" 
        id="mail" 
        onclick="select(this);" 
        readonly="" 
        title="" 
        type="text" 
        value="wukur@storj99.com"/>]
```

How can I extract using beautifulsoup the email : "wukur@storj99.com"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extracting an attribute value with beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612548/extracting-an-attribute-value-with-beautifulsoup)

Comment: Use: `soup.find('input', {'id':'mail'}).get('value')`

Answer (score 0):

you could use this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
text = '''<input class="mail opentip" data-original-title="Your temporary Email address" data-placement="bottom" id="mail" onclick="select(this);" readonly="" title="" type="text" value="wukur@storj99.com"/>'''

parse = BeautifulSoup(text, 'lxml')

for z in parse.find_all('input', {'class':"mail opentip"}):
    print(z['value'])
```