# Extracting HTML content with Python using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hi I am using the beautiful soup library to parse content from an html page.

I use the following script the get to the part of the page I want to:

```
review_list = soup.find(class_="review_list_score_breakdown_right")
```

```html
<span class=" review_list_score_breakdown_right">
 <ul class="review_score_breakdown_list list_tighten clearfix" data-et-view="bLTQHcXJVNRCSPOMcAQJO:1 bLTQHcXJVNRCSPOMcAQJO:3 " id="review_list_score_breakdown">
  <li class="clearfix one_col" data-question="hotel_clean">
   <p class="review_score_name">
    Cleanliness
   </p>
   <div class="score_bar">
    <div class="score_bar_value" data-score="100" style="width: 100%;">
    </div>
   </div>
   <p class="review_score_value">
    10
   </p>
  </li>
  <li class="clearfix one_col" data-question="hotel_comfort">
   <p class="review_score_name">
    Comfort
   </p>
   <div class="score_bar">
    <div class="score_bar_value" data-score="100" style="width: 100%;">
    </div>
   </div>
   <p class="review_score_value">
    10
   </p>
  </li>
  <li class="clearfix one_col" data-question="hotel_services">
   <p class="review_score_name">
    Facilities
   </p>
   <div class="score_bar">
    <div class="score_bar_value" data-score="100" style="width: 100%;">
    </div>
   </div>
   <p class="review_score_value">
    10
   </p>
  </li>
  <li class="clearfix one_col" data-question="hotel_staff">
   <p class="review_score_name">
    Staff
   </p>
   <div class="score_bar">
    <div class="score_bar_value" data-score="100" style="width: 100%;">
    </div>
   </div>
   <p class="review_score_value">
    10
   </p>
  </li>
  <li class="clearfix one_col" data-question="hotel_value">
   <p class="review_score_name">
    Value for money
   </p>
   <div class="score_bar">
    <div class="score_bar_value" data-score="100" style="width: 100%;">
    </div>
   </div>
   <p class="review_score_value">
    10
   </p>
  </li>
  <li class="clearfix one_col" data-question="hotel_wifi">
   <p class="review_score_name">
    Free WiFi
   </p>
   <div class="score_bar">
    <div class="score_bar_value" data-score="100" style="width: 100%;">
    </div>
   </div>
   <p class="review_score_value">
    10
   </p>
  </li>
  <li class="clearfix one_col" data-question="hotel_location">
   <p class="review_score_name">
    Location
   </p>
   <div class="score_bar">
    <div class="score_bar_value" data-score="100" style="width: 100%;">
    </div>
   </div>
   <p class="review_score_value">
    10
   </p>
  </li>
 </ul>
</span>
```

I need to extract the score from the data-question tags. For example, if I want to know the hotel comfort score, I'd need to access `data-question= "hotel_confort"` I've tried with the function `find()` but it doesn't work.

Comment: looks like all of your scores have the same `100` value. So, what's the point? If a real markup could differ - post a more representative markup

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is the `attrs` find query.
Your question is similar to [Extracting an attribute value with beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612548/extracting-an-attribute-value-with-beautifulsoup#2612577)

I will make it a bit specific for your case.

```
review = soup.find(class_="review_list_score_breakdown_right")
input = review.find(attrs={"data-question" : "hotel-comfort"})
output = input['value']
```

It's been awhile since I used bs4 so please debug the code.

Edit:
Here's some working code taken from your example string

```
review = soup.find('span', {'class' : "review_list_score_breakdown_right"})
input = review.find_all(attrs={"data-question": "hotel_comfort"})
print(input) #print the html extract which you can go down further.
```

Comment: Sorry, let me try that offline and figure it out

Comment: I checked my answer and it is alright. But as I mentioned you can't just copy paste. You see I have a typo in `hotel-comfort` correct it and it will work. Skipe the `output=input['value']` and just print the input to proceed further down the tree. I updated my answer with a working solution I tested locally.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `hotel_confort` attrs in your codes.

```
    review = soup.find(class_="review_list_score_breakdown_right")
    hotel = review.find(attrs={"data-question" : "hotel_comfort"})
```

This code returns

`<li class="clearfix one_col" data-question="hotel_comfort"> ..... </li>`