# How to Extract Text from Inside " Python

Tags: python, string, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, substring

Doing some web scraping and I need to extract the date from inside a HTML tag that looks something like this:

```
<div class="DateTime" title="Feb 21, 2018 at 1:27 AM">Feb 21</div>
```

I need to pull out the text at `title`, as this is the full date.

I have tried:

```
s = '<div class="DateTime" title="Feb 21, 2018 at 1:27 AM">Feb 21</div>'
l = s.split('"')[1::2]
print l[1]
```

However I get the error "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extracting an attribute value with beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612548/extracting-an-attribute-value-with-beautifulsoup)

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the error, [see here](http://www.compileonline.com/execute_python_online.php)

Answer (score 3):

From official documentation:

> The tag `<b id="boldest">` has an attribute “id” whose value is
>   “boldest”. You can access a tag’s attributes by treating the tag like
>   a dictionary:
>
> ```
> tag['id']
> ```
>
> gives the output: `'boldest'`

You can access that dictionary directly as .attrs:

```
>>> tag.attrs
{u'id': 'boldest'}
```

And I assume that the variable `s` is a soup:

```
s = #tag taken using beautiful soup
```

you can access the attribute associated with it like this:

```
s['attribute']
```

so in your case:

```
l = s['title']
print(l)
```

Comment: If that is the case then accept it as an answer for future references.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of split I would suggest using regex as follows:

```
import re
s = '<div class="DateTime" title="Feb 21, 2018 at 1:27 AM">Feb 21</div>'
print re.findall(pattern="title=\"(.*?)\"", string=s)[0]
```

**output**

```
Feb 21, 2018 at 1:27 AM
```

Comment: This doesn't work with `s = '<div title="Feb 21, 2018 at 1:27 AM" class="DateTime" >Feb 21</div>`. You can add a `?`to stop at the first `"`, like so: `pattern="title=\"(.*?)\""`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    x =s.split('"')
    print(x[3])
```

try above

Comment: your answer is perfectly works in given example. What if an another attribute come between ?

Comment: regexps are costly so in performance point of view i assumed it would be same

Comment: your answer is right only and its better that regex but only for this example. If OP is trying with another string that may have more attributes your answer wont work. in such situations regex is usefull because it will search and take the value.

Comment: The thing that can try with your code is make dict instead of list as attribute name as keys and values by splitting then you can easly take `d['title']`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import re
s = '<div class="DateTime" title="Feb 21, 2018 at 1:27 AM">Feb 21</div>'
re.findall(r'title="(.*?)"', s)[0]
```

You will get

```
Feb 21, 2018 at 1:27 AM
```