# How to get CSS links using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have a [webpage](http://jordanbaron.me/updatedtextasticsite) that I am scraping using Beautiful Soup. I've got the HTML, but now I need the CSS. I have tried using `soup.findAll('link', {'rel': 'stylesheet'})` but I can figure out how to get the filename from the 1st index of the returned list, `<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>`

I have tried using regex, which I'm not very good at, but I'm not sure how to get it to work.

So, is there a BeautifulSoup function that I can use or do I have to go the route I'm already taking?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using BeautifulSoup4

```
for link in soup.find_all('link', href=True):
    print "Found the URL:", link['href']
```

If your using version 3

```
for link in soup.findAll('link', href=True):
    print "Found the URL:", link['href']
```

Comment: Another way of finding the link, just tried it so thought I would share.  BeautifulSoup4: pass the tag's rel attribute as a filter -
 `link_tags = soup.findAll("link", rel="stylesheet")` and then `for each_tag in link_tags: csslink = each_tag["href"]` - source https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612548/extracting-an-attribute-value-with-beautifulsoup