# Python Beautifulsoup Getting Attribute Value

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm having difficulty getting the proper syntax to extract the value of an attribute in Beautifulsoup with HTML 5.0.

So I've isolated the occurrence of a tag in my `soup` using the proper syntax where there is an HTML 5 issue:

```
tags = soup.find_all(attrs={"data-topic":"recUpgrade"})
```

Taking just tags[1]:

```
date = tags[1].find(attrs={"data-datenews":True})
```

and date here is:

```
<span class="invisible" data-datenews="2018-05-25 06:02:19" data-idnews="2736625" id="horaCompleta"></span>
```

But now I want to extract the date time "2018-05-25 06:02:19".  Can't get the syntax.

Insight/help please.

Comment: You can get attribute value from element, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2612577/6546734)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can access the attrs using key-value pair

**Ex:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s = """<span class="invisible" data-datenews="2018-05-25 06:02:19" data-idnews="2736625" id="horaCompleta"></span>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(s, "html.parser")
print(soup.span["data-datenews"])
```

**Output:**

```
2018-05-25 06:02:19
```

Comment: Interesting.  So parse again? (I used the parser, not shown, to get `soup')

Comment: so I try this syntax:  `print(date.span["data-datenews"])` and I get `TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`.  `print(date["data-datenews"])` works.  Why?

Comment: you need to find the span tag first