# Python 3 Web Scrape & Beautiful Soup Tag Attribute

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am practicing on Beautiful Soup and am after a products price, description and item number. The first 2 are text and are easy to get. The third is an attribute of the tag data-trade-price as seen below:-

```
<div class="price-group display-metro has-promo-price  medium ng-scope" ng-class="{'has-trade-price': ShowTrade}" data-trade-price="221043">
```

I am after the numbers such as **221043** which is loaded in by the page. IE - all 24 item numbers matching all 24 products

My code is:-

```
import requests  
r = requests.get('http://www.supercheapauto.com.au/store/car-care/wash-wax-polish/1021762?page=1&pageSize=24&sort=-ProductSummaryPurchasesWeighted%2C-ProductSummaryPurchases')

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')  
results = soup.find_all('div', class_='details')

for result in results: 
    try:
        SKU = result.select_one("data-trade-price")
    except AttributeError: SKU = "N/A"

    DESC = result.find('div', class_='title').text.strip().upper()
    PRICE = result.find('span', class_='currency').text.strip().upper()

    print(SKU,'\t', DESC,'\t', PRICE)
```

What is the syntax to get the item number from the soup?

Sorry - I am after the syntax that can iterate through the page of 24 products and recover the 24 different item numbers. The example given was to show the part of the attribute value that I was after. I ran the given answer and it works. I am unsure of how to integrate into the code given as the variations I use do not. Any suggestions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Beautifulsoup Getting Attribute Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50533363/python-beautifulsoup-getting-attribute-value)

Comment: Might as well use `re`. It looks like this: `<div class="product" ng-controller="ProductListItemController" ng-init="productPLU = '221043'">
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the attribute just like a dictionary.

**Ex:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s = """<div class="price-group display-metro has-promo-price medium ng-scope" ng-class="{'has-trade-price': ShowTrade}" data-trade-price="221043"<\div>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(s, "html.parser")
print( soup.find("div", class_="price-group display-metro has-promo-price medium ng-scope").attrs["data-trade-price"] )
```

*or*

```
print( soup.find("div", class_="price-group display-metro has-promo-price medium ng-scope")["data-trade-price"] )
```

**Output:**

```
221043
```

Comment: I don't think that'll work with requests when that value is likely generated by Angular

Comment: It looks like the page at the URL given has `data-trade-price` in the source, so it should be fine.

Comment: Sorry - I am after the syntax that can iterate through the page of 24 products and recover the 24 different item numbers. The example given was to show the part of the attribute value that I was after. I ran the given answer and it works. I am unsure of how to integrate into the code given as the variations I use do not. Any suggestions.

Comment: Thanks Rakesh - re-checked the HTML output and noticed that not all classes were the same based on different prices. Shortened the find to (class_='price-group'.attrs['data-trade-price]) and it pulled all the data I was after.