# Get the url from custom tag in beautifulsoup$

Tags: python, django, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to get url the from custom html tag.
So im extracting the img like this

```
qwe =   []
for x in carList:
  try:
     carPicture  = x.find('img', class_="lazyload", attrs={"data-src":True})
  except: 
     carPicture   = static("images/human.jpg")
qwe.append(carPicture)
```

The result of that is:

```
<img class="lazyload" data-src="https://prod.pictures.autoscout24.net/listing-images/58878dbf-083a-4685-af3a-f745a6534426_cdde08fb-999b-488a-86c8-d252bcadaaff.jpg/420x315.jpg"/>
```

How can i get only the link from data-src tag?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Beautifulsoup Getting Attribute Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50533363/python-beautifulsoup-getting-attribute-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the [`docs`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), You can use the below snippet

`carPicture["data-src"]`

Output:

```
https://prod.pictures.autoscout24.net/listing-images/58878dbf-083a-4685-af3a-f745a6534426_cdde08fb-999b-488a-86c8-d252bcadaaff.jpg/420x315.jpg
```