# How to find the value of a specific attribute of a <div >

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Well, first of all I am not sure if it is an atrribute. If it is not, please tell me the right name.
The page has a div tag with the general format:

```
<div class="top" data-src="/a/path/to/another/page.html" id="id_random" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
```

I want to retrieve the value of 'data-src' attribute (?) above, which is "/a/path/to/another/page.html", using python/bs4.

I already have the html code above in a variable named target_div and I have tried things like:

```
target_div.find(id='data-src')
```

or

```
target_div.find ('meta', {'name':'data-src'})
```

or

```
target_div.find (attrs={'name' : 'data-src'})
```

Please, how to find "data-src" and its value inside a div ?

best regards,

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612548/extracting-an-attribute-value-with-beautifulsoup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

target_div = '''<div class="top" data-src="/a/path/to/another/page.html" id="id_random" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(target_div, 'html.parser')
print soup.find('div', class_='top')['data-src']
```

The result should be:

```
/a/path/to/another/page.html
```