# Need to take 'href' value from 'a' tag in following output

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am writing a Python 3 code for web scraping using beautiful soup. Below is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS


soup = BS(html, 'html.parser')

# finding all 'a' tags of the page whose class was 'image'
containers = soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'image'})

print(len(containers))  # containers length is 15
```

Now I need to write a loop and find out all the href components from the 'a' tag. How do I do this ?

Comment: Sorry, we [can't accept images of code, errors or output](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Post those as *text*, so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: See the duplicate, just use `for link in containers:` then `link['href']`. You really want to use `page_soup.select('a.image[href]')` instead; that selects the same `a` tags with the `image` class, but adds an additional requirement that those tags are guaranteed to have a `href` attribute. `.select()` lets you use CSS selectors to find matches.

Comment: Take a look at a similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612548/extracting-an-attribute-value-with-beautifulsoup)