# BeautifulSoup find attribute value in any tag

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

How to find value of certain attribute using bs4? For example, I need to find all values of `src` attribute, it could be in any tag of my html document.

Comment: Possible duplicate [Extracting an attribute value with beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612548/extracting-an-attribute-value-with-beautifulsoup)

Comment: no, there is question about fixed attribute value, I can't fix this value, I need to find it:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get('http://your.url')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')

attr_src = []
for tag in soup():
    if 'src' in tag.attrs:
        attr_src.append(tag.get('src'))
print(attr_src)
```

Comment: You are welcome :-)
Could you just accept the answer if it's good?

Comment: sure, in 4 minutes:)

Answer (score 1):

Just use an attribute selector (that's what it's intended for). More efficient.

```
values = [item['src'] for item in soup.select('[src]')]
```

You can extend by adding the required string/substring of a desired value by adding = substring/string after the attribute i.e. [src="mystring"]

Example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

res = requests.get('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55060825/beautifulsoup-find-attribute-value-in-any-tag/55062258#55062258')
soup = bs(res.content, 'lxml')
values = [item['src'] for item in soup.select('[src]')]
print(values)
```