# Extracting web-page content with beautiful soup

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the price of an item off of an eCommerce website using beautiful soup with python 3. What else do I have to do to extract the price from my first pull?

I have tried other combinations of the code, but do not have a strong understanding of this method.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://www.walmart.com/ip/GoGreen-Power-6-Outlet-Surge-Protector-16103MS-2-5-cord-White/46097919')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

price_hide = soup.find(class_='price-characteristic')
print(price_hide)

wprice = price_hide.find_all(content)
print(wprice)
```

First print function works

```
<span class="price-characteristic" content="3.98" itemprop="price">3</span>
```

Second one not so much.

I would expect the content price of 3.98 to be printed

Comment: `price_hide['content']` or `price_hide.get('content')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extracting an attribute value with beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612548/extracting-an-attribute-value-with-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easier than you think, try out the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = requests.get('https://www.walmart.com/ip/GoGreen-Power-6-Outlet-Surge-Protector-16103MS-2-5-cord-White/46097919')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

price_hide = soup.find(class_='price-characteristic')
print(price_hide)

wprice = price_hide["content"]
print(wprice)
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: This answer was great and the technique works on everything I have tried up to this html code below 
`<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
<div class="row gray-bkg marg-top10">
<div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-3 price-lg">$6.92 <span class="unit"> / ea </span></div>` 
How do I get  the 6.92?