# I'm having trouble grabbing an html input value using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I need to grab the value of the attribute `value` inside this HTML element

```
<option value="1129070-040" data-size="US9.5" data-stock="In_Stock" data-morecomingsoon="true">
```

I can't seem to find a way in [bs4 documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Comment: Can you provide the entire HTML or a link to a page?

Comment: Is the problem that you don't know how to find that specific element, or that you don't know how to access the `value` attribute?

Comment: I don't how to find a specific value of an attr

Comment: Once you have the element, it should just be `element['value']`.

Comment: @PeterSutton I want to find "1129070-035" in ```<option value="1129070-035" data-size="US7" data-stock="In_Stock" data-morecomingsoon="true">```

Comment: could you please provide what you have already done? example of your code or something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extracting an attribute value with beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612548/extracting-an-attribute-value-with-beautifulsoup)

Comment: @VladimirSemashkin
```product_page = requests.get('https://www.net-a-porter.com/de/en/product/1129070')
soup = BeautifulSoup (product_page.content, "lxml")
product_id = soup.find(here i need to find that value)```.
The value is inside this html element ```<option value="1129070-035" data-size="US7" data-stock="In_Stock" data-morecomingsoon="true">```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you included in your question you can get the value of the `value` attribute using this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

html = """<option value="1129070-040" data-size="US9.5" data-stock="In_Stock" data-morecomingsoon="true">"""    
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")    
value = soup.find("option")["value"]

print(value)
```

hope this helps

Comment: almost @fozoro
 ```product_page = requests.get('https://www.net-a-porter.com/de/en/product/1129070')
soup = BeautifulSoup (product_page.content, "lxml")
product_id = soup.find(here i need to find that value)```

The value is inside this html element ```<option value="1129070-035" data-size="US7" data-stock="In_Stock" data-morecomingsoon="true">```

Comment: what if there's more ("option")["value"] in the webpage, how to find a specific one with exact elements that i gave you like data_size and, data_stock and data_morecomingsoon

Comment: hmmmm it seems that the website is rendered using Javascript. Which makes it nearly impossible to scrap using `requests`

Comment: not a problem i can use selenium, just wanna know how to find that specific value

Comment: do you want to get one or all of them?

Comment: let's say just one, with data_size="US7'' and data_stock="InStock"

Comment: in this case replace my `value` variable with `value = soup.find("option",{"data_size":"US7","data_stock"="InStock"})["value"]`

Comment: Thanks man! do you recommend using node,js/cheerio for a webpage that's rendered in js or stick with py/sb4 and use selenium? I wan parsing to be fast though.

Comment: never used node.js/cheerio I think selenium is a solid choice in your case though I can't really give any tips on it (I hardly ever use it myself). Thanks for accepting the answer, best of luck!