# Can´t reach to this specific CSS / HTML tag Python web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Editing:

So, I am doing a webscraping using beautiful soup.

I´ve tried a lot of things but can´t reach this part of the code:

[image]

I tried this (and other derivations) but it returns an empty list:

```
iptu = [iptu.get_text() for iptu in soup.find_all("article", {"data-clickstream":"iptuPrices"})]
```

How can I send the HTML as its very big to copy and paste?!

Comment: You'll need to provide some more context on it please. Are you using BeautifulSoup on this one? Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612548/extracting-an-attribute-value-with-beautifulsoup for a potential solution.

Comment: Please provide the html/link.

Comment: Here is the link: https://www.zapimoveis.com.br/aluguel/casas-de-condominio/agr+rj++barra-e-recreio/

But this link changes the HTML aleatory!!

Answer (score 1):

From your image, it looks like the data you want is in a JSON string in an attribute of the article tag. If so, then perhaps something like this can get you started.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import requests

url = 'https://www.zapimoveis.com.br/aluguel/casas-de-condominio/agr+rj++barra-e-recreio/'

user_agent = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
resp = requests.get(url, headers=user_agent)

soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, features="html.parser")

prices = []
for i, a in enumerate(soup.find_all('article')):
    b = a.get('data-clickstream')
    if not b: continue
    o = json.loads(b)
    prices.append(sum(map(float, o['iptuPrices'])))

print(prices)
```

Comment: thanks for helping! I tried but did not work out.. ! How can I spot the difference between Json and Html ?

Comment: Edited my answer to read the data from the URL given. Here's a [working demo](https://repl.it/repls/OilyMealyArgument)