# Using Beautifulsoup to pull attribute

Tags: beautifulsoup

Trying to parse this html:

```
    </thead>
    <tbody>
                        <tr>
            <td class="rank">
                1.
            </td>
            <td class="name">
                                            <a href="https://hoopshype.com/player/stephen-curry/salary/">
                        Stephen Curry                           </a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="color:black" class="hh-salaries-sorted" data-value="40231758">
                    $40,231,758                     </td>
```

How do I pull "color:black" from here?

Comment: extract the style attribute as you would with a dictionary. There are lots of answers to this on stackoverflow to guide you. E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612548/extracting-an-attribute-value-with-beautifulsoup

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extracting an attribute value with beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612548/extracting-an-attribute-value-with-beautifulsoup)

Comment: Thank you @QHarr, very similar to the below answer.  When I was searching initially I didn't catch this entry -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
data = """
    </thead>
    <tbody>
                        <tr>
            <td class="rank">
                1.
            </td>
            <td class="name">
                                            <a href="https://hoopshype.com/player/stephen-curry/salary/">
                        Stephen Curry                           </a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="color:black" class="hh-salaries-sorted" data-value="40231758">
                    $40,231,758                     </td>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.findAll('td', attrs={'class': 'hh-salaries-sorted'}):
    print(item.get('style'))
```

Output:

```
color:black
```