# how to scrape value using id in beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to store the text of **value** in  a variable  **status**
which is either **Discharging** or **Charging**

```
<input id="batterystatus" value="Discharging" type="hidden">
```

I have tried to store text in status

```
site="http://jiofi.local.html/"
opener=uo(site)
page=opener.read()
opener.close()
parser = bs(page, "html.parser")
status=parser.find(id='batterystatus')
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried and didn't work?

Comment: try this: ```status = parser.find(id='batterystatus')['value']```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extracting an attribute value with beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612548/extracting-an-attribute-value-with-beautifulsoup)

Comment: Had you done any research? It took my two seconds to find a duplicate question, never mind the actual documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
Print(status['value'])
```