# extract specific data (HTML utime) with Beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I need to export the data-utime from the following line:

```
<abbr title="23/1/20, 10:52 &#x3c0;.&#x3bc;." data-utime="1579805539" data-shorten="1" class="_5ptz">
```

How can I do that? Played with `soup.find()` for a while but didn't find solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extracting an attribute value with beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612548/extracting-an-attribute-value-with-beautifulsoup)

Comment: If your url is public you can share it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `find` and then a `get` to have the value of the attribute.

Like this:

```
utime = soup.find('abbr', {'class': '_5ptz'}).get('data-utime')
```

Comment: i get `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'` when attempt it.

Comment: what is the url of your website? The Error you have meens soup didn't find the `abbr` tag. It can be loaded by javascript