# Python beautifulsoup4 library find_all() function problem

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How the take just "data-ds-appid"?

```
<a href="https://store.steampowered.com/app/730/CounterStrike_Global_Offensive/?snr=1_241_4_action_104" class="tab_item  "  data-ds-appid="730" data-ds-itemkey="App_730"
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you clarify what the issue is?

Comment: I just want to take "data-ds-appid =" 730" --------- soup.findAll(class_="tab_item", attrs={"data-ds-appid"} this code take all html block.

Comment: Alright, so which part are you struggling with? Have you tried anything, done any research? Have you read the BeautifulSoup docs?

Comment: I read the documents, but I couldn't find anything about it.

Comment: _I read the documents, but I couldn't find anything about it._ How is that possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extracting an attribute value with beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612548/extracting-an-attribute-value-with-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access a tag’s attributes by treating the tag like a dictionary [1](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = '''<h1>asdfas</h1>
<p>asd aasdfas dfasd
<a href="https://store.steampowered.com/app/730/CounterStrike_Global_Offensive/?snr=1_241_4_action_104" class="tab_item  "  data-ds-appid="730" data-ds-itemkey="App_730">asdfas</a>
</p>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

idlist = [element['data-ds-appid'] for element in soup.find_all(class_="tab_item")]

print(idlist)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612548/extracting-an-attribute-value-with-beautifulsoup