# How to get data from span tag which have custom characteristics? (BeautifulSoup)

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I have following span tag. How can I scrape `xuRMlBoIUcI7nAJktBcJvPByp1DLE4aPGzq3JNiRKsdNqUkVSJBY%2BggxRhp0GcRx4Gw4lWQxbTk%3D`
which is assigned to data-slug?

```
    <span data-ju-jspjrvxy="" 
    data-slug="xuRMlBoIUcI7nAJktBcJvPByp1DLE4aPGzq3JNiRKsdNqUkVSJBY%2BggxRhp0GcRx4Gw4lWQxbTk%3D" 
    data-gtm-clickedelement="CTA button" data-gtm-offer="" data-ju-wvxjoly-pk="303795"
 data-gtm-voucher-id="303795" class="businessinsiderus-voucher-button-holder clear">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my understanding of your problem is correct you want to scrape an attribute of a tag.
If this is in fact your problem the following link will provide a solution:
[Extracting an attribute value with beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612548/extracting-an-attribute-value-with-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 0):

If `s` is your data string, then use the regex module:

```
import re
match = re.findall('data\-slug=\"()\"',str(s))
```

Comment: I want that full string assigned to data-slug.

Comment: Yes, this will return an array  of strings of all possible matches. if only one string is required use, match[0]

Comment: I have multiple span tags and each has an unique value assigned to data-slug. Will it work on that too.

Comment: Yes, it will return a of multiple strings. in the input string s contain multiple data-slugs

Comment: It is better to use str(s) in the findall function, I have edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

    content = 'your html span text here'

    soup = BS(content,parser='html', features='lxml')

    dict_of_spantag_attributes_and_values = soup.span.attrs

    for i,j in dict_of_spantag_attributes_and_values.items():

        print(f'{i}:{j}')
```