# in python, how I get values between specific string in web page

Tags: python

can you please help me , I was thinking for long time but did not know what to write :(

**I need two values : asin  and price

asin = # I need the values that is between `<div data-asin="` and `"` in the webpage source code

price = # I need the values that is between `<span class="a-price" data-a-size="l" data-a-color="base"><span class="a-offscreen">SAR` and `</span>`  in the webpage source code

Example web page
https://www.amazon.sa/s?i=electronics&bbn=16966387031&rh=n:12463162031%2Cn:12463163031%2Cn:16966387031%2Cp_6:A2XPWB6MYN7ZDK&s=price-asc-rank&dc&fst=as:off&qid=1592532915&rnid=16641811031&ref=sr_st_price-asc-rank&dc&page=1

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import requests
import time
   
number_of_threads = 6

out_filename = time.strftime('soldbysouq-shopanddodandsupermarket' + "%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")

headers = "price,asin,\n"

def extract_data_from_url_func(url):
    print(url)
    response = requests.get(url)
    page_soup = soup(response.text, "html.parser")

    containers = # tried a lot of things without luck
    output = ''
    for container in containers:
        asin = # I need the values that is between **<div data-asin="** and **"** in the webpage source code 
        price = # I need the values that is between **<span class="a-price" data-a-size="l" data-a-color="base"><span class="a-offscreen">SAR**  and **</span>**  in the webpage source code 
       
          
        output_list = [price,asin,]
        output = output + ",".join(output_list) + "\n"
        print(output)

    return output

with open("amazonlist1.csv", "r") as fr:
    URLS = list(map(lambda x: x.strip(), fr.readlines()))

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=number_of_threads) as executor:
    results = executor.map( extract_data_from_url_func, URLS)
    responses = []
    for result in results:
        responses.append(result)


with open(out_filename, "w", encoding='utf-8-sig') as fw:
  fw.write(headers)
  for response in responses:
      fw.write(response + "\n")
```

Comment: This could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612548/extracting-an-attribute-value-with-beautifulsoup and https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes

Comment: thank you for prompt reply dear @DamiãoMartins, but I am still stuck

Comment: @user13602012 check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will solve your `data-asin` thing:

```
items = page_soup.select('div[data-asin]')
for item in items:
    print(item['data-asin'])
```

---

```
B0887QV8BB
B0856Q8K78
B01ISO92V2
B07N3XNX77
B07XQXPF21
B07VKNWD5P
.
.
.
.
```

---

```
price = [i.text for i in page_soup.findAll('span', class_="a-offscreen")]
```

**Edit:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time

url = 'https://www.amazon.sa/s?i=electronics&bbn=16966387031&rh=n:12463162031%2Cn:12463163031%2Cn:16966387031%2Cp_6:A2XPWB6MYN7ZDK&s=price-asc-rank&dc&fst=as:off&qid=1592532915&rnid=16641811031&ref=sr_st_price-asc-rank&dc&page=1'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.set_window_size(1024, 600)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

soup=bs(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
time.sleep(3)

items = soup.select('div[data-asin]')
for item in items:
    print(item['data-asin'])
```

---

```
B07N7CPZ5V
B0856YYBC6
B0856WVLDH
B07N6PYYZL
B07P9WKRHD
B07WCVVBLT
B07Q1D8XWP
.
.
.
```

Don't forget to install the required package: `pip install webdriver-manager`

### Edit2:

**Full Code:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time

url = 'https://www.amazon.sa/s?i=electronics&bbn=16966387031&rh=n:12463162031%2Cn:12463163031%2Cn:16966387031%2Cp_6:A2XPWB6MYN7ZDK&s=price-asc-rank&dc&fst=as:off&qid=1592532915&rnid=16641811031&ref=sr_st_price-asc-rank&dc&page=1'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.set_window_size(1024, 600)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

soup=bs(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
time.sleep(3)

items = soup.select('div[data-asin]')
dasin = [i['data-asin'] for i in items]
items = soup.findAll('span', class_= 'a-price')
price = [float(i.text.split()[0]) for i in items]
info = list(zip(dasin, price))
```

---

**info:**

```
[('B07N7CPZ5V', 3.24),
 ('B0856YYBC6', 3.97),
 ('B0856WVLDH', 3.97),
 ('B07N6PYYZL', 3.97),
 ('B07P9WKRHD', 4.0),
 ('B07WCVVBLT', 39.0),
 ('B07Q1D8XWP', 5.0),
 ('B07NDY31Q2', 111.93),
 ('B07N78MQM2', 5.29),
 ('B083B1K2NF', 5.29),
 ('B0856T4P15', 5.29),
 ('B07MMK4KQT', 6.04),
 ('B083X1YGWK', 6.48),
 ('B07PKHR3ZZ', 6.61),
 ('B07NF1C183', 6.61),
 ('B07P9W46JT', 6.61),
 ('B07P5HWJK7', 6.61),
 ('B0857BQGJP', 6.74),
 ('B085714YYH', 7.39),
 ('B0856Y5G3J', 7.94),
 ('B0856XLCQD', 7.94),
 ('B0856QQWCY', 7.94),
 ('B07NF3RZN5', 7.94),
 ('B07NF17XYP', 7.94),
 ('', 7.94)]
```

Comment: the problem is non of the result values (price or asin) is matched web page , real ASIN B07N7CPZ5V B0856YYBC6 B0856WVLDH B07N6PYYZL B07P9WKRHD B07WCVVBLT B07Q1D8XWP B07NDY31Q2 B07N78MQM2 B083B1K2NF B0856T4P15 B07MMK4KQT B083X1YGWK B07PKHR3ZZ B07NF1C183 B07P9W46JT B07P5HWJK7 B0857BQGJP B085714YYH B0856Y5G3J B0856XLCQD B0856QQWCY B07NF3RZN5 B07NF17XYP

Comment: BUT the python code give me different ASIN than it is really in the page (This is not correct ASIN) B0887QV8BB B0856Q8K78 B01ISO92V2 B07N3XNX77 B07XQXPF21 B07VKNWD5P B07RCG7VSB B083TK2W87 B07CXGPW8G B07ZRCT1VH B07P6YKSQP B085JVBMTT B089G813SB B07B88KQZ8 B08521415W B06XGBC43Z B07Y3KGRL8 B084ZTCM1G B0856Y5G11 B075THDT3M B01GGKYKQM B0851ZWC87 B084FFWSLH B0871TDTLV

Comment: The reason for this is that page is getting updated using javascript. At first they were showing something else which your beautiful soup captured it. But later some time the page gets updated. So you need to use selenium for it as the page gets rendered using js.

Comment: you are real life hero and life saver, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests
import re

def function(url):
    
    print(url)
    response = requests.get(url)
    page_soup = soup(response.text, "html.parser")

    # all objects with data-asin attr with any value aside from empty (there is empty data-asin on page without price or item)
    containers = page_soup.find_all(attrs={'data-asin': re.compile(r'.+')})
    for container in containers:
        asin = container['data-asin'] # accessing attrs of Tag is simple as that
        print(asin)
        # get all a-price class elements (should be one) and their child, then take string from first
        # output without [0] is ['1,699.00 ريال', None]
        price = [item.string for item in container.find_next(attrs={'class': 'a-price'}).children][0]
        print(price)

# example output for your URL (for me is Egypt region for some reason so it's Egyptian pounds)
# https://www.amazon.sa/s?i=electronics&bbn=16966387031&rh=n:12463162031%2Cn:12463163031%2Cn:16966387031%2Cp_6:A2XPWB6MYN7ZDK&s=price-asc-rank&dc&fst=as:off&qid=1592532915&rnid=16641811031&ref=sr_st_price-asc-rank&dc&page=1
# B0887QV8BB
# 939.00 ريال
# B0856Q8K78
# 445.36 ريال
# B01ISO92V2
# 85.82 ريال
# B07N3XNX77
# 92.00 ريال
# B07XQXPF21
# 1,794.00 ريال
# B07VKNWD5P
# 262.45 ريال
# B07RCG7VSB
# 84.53 ريال
# B083TK2W87
# 15.87 ريال
# B07CXGPW8G
# 118.00 ريال
# B07ZRCT1VH
# 54.75 ريال
# B07P6YKSQP
# 69.00 ريال
# B085JVBMTT
# 322.20 ريال
# B089G813SB
# 499.00 ريال
# B07B88KQZ8
# 82.95 ريال
# B08521415W
# 995.00 ريال
# B06XGBC43Z
# 18.50 ريال
# B07Y3KGRL8
# 3,104.00 ريال
# B084ZTCM1G
# 1,399.00 ريال
# B0856Y5G11
# 995.00 ريال
# B075THDT3M
# 129.00 ريال
# B01GGKYKQM
# 11.00 ريال
# B0851ZWC87
# 399.00 ريال
# B084FFWSLH
# 799.00 ريال
# B0871TDTLV
# 1,699.00 ريال
```

Comment: what is driving me crazy is the values for this page should be B07N7CPZ5V 3.24
B0856YYBC6 3.97
B0856WVLDH 3.97
B07N6PYYZL 3.97
B07P9WKRHD 4
B07WCVVBLT 5
B07Q1D8XWP 5.29
B07NDY31Q2 5.29
B07N78MQM2 5.29
B083B1K2NF 6.04
B0856T4P15 6.48
B07MMK4KQT 6.61
B083X1YGWK 6.61
B07PKHR3ZZ 6.61
B07NF1C183 6.61
B07P9W46JT 6.74
B07P5HWJK7 7.39
B0857BQGJP 7.94
B085714YYH 7.94
B0856Y5G3J 7.94
B0856XLCQD 7.94
B0856QQWCY 7.94
B07NF3RZN5 7.94
B07NF17XYP 7.94

Comment: It's just an issue of parsing. I gave you values of those elements and strings of prices elements corresponding to those container values. How to parse prices is up to you :)

Comment: Dear @vrnvorona , the problem is non of the result values (price or asin) is matched web page , real ASIN B07N7CPZ5V
B0856YYBC6
B0856WVLDH
B07N6PYYZL
B07P9WKRHD
B07WCVVBLT
B07Q1D8XWP
B07NDY31Q2
B07N78MQM2
B083B1K2NF
B0856T4P15
B07MMK4KQT
B083X1YGWK
B07PKHR3ZZ
B07NF1C183
B07P9W46JT
B07P5HWJK7
B0857BQGJP
B085714YYH
B0856Y5G3J
B0856XLCQD
B0856QQWCY
B07NF3RZN5
B07NF17XYP
      ------

Comment: BUT the python code give me different ASIN than it is really  in the page (This is not correct ASIN) B0887QV8BB
B0856Q8K78
B01ISO92V2
B07N3XNX77
B07XQXPF21
B07VKNWD5P
B07RCG7VSB
B083TK2W87
B07CXGPW8G
B07ZRCT1VH
B07P6YKSQP
B085JVBMTT
B089G813SB
B07B88KQZ8
B08521415W
B06XGBC43Z
B07Y3KGRL8
B084ZTCM1G
B0856Y5G11
B075THDT3M
B01GGKYKQM
B0851ZWC87
B084FFWSLH
B0871TDTLV

Comment: That's not the code issue, but how page works. We are using different client, so items and/or their order may and will be different. It's not ASINs are different, but items.

Comment: @vrnvorona: this is the case where one have to use selenium. Because they are updating the page using script. After using selenium the result will be the expected one.

Comment: I agree, i would do that with selenium as well. Plus easier to navigate pages if needed.