# BeautifulSoup, Extracting strings within HTML information, ResultSet objects

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, resultset

Here is what I get for the Code

Input:
`contents = bs.find_all('div', {'class':'result_list'})`

Output:

```
<div class="result_list" id="search-list"><div class="sight_item" data-address="广州市番禺区大石镇105国道大石段593号" 
data-children-count="17" data-districts="广东·广州·广州长隆旅游度假区" data-foreign="false" data-id="4281924223"
data-point="113.321711,23.007944"
```

So I want to extract the information inside the ResultSet.

For examples,

I want to get the 'data-address' and 'data-point'.

So what should I do?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612548/extracting-an-attribute-value-with-beautifulsoup) might help

Answer (score 0):

First there should be a closing div tag for the html code.
So lets make the output of contents this

```html
<div class="result_list" id="search-list">
  <div class="sight_item" data-address="广州市番禺区大石镇105国道大石段593号" 
    data-children-count="17" data-districts="广东·广州·广州长隆旅游度假区" 
    data-foreign="false" data-id="4281924223"
    data-point="113.321711,23.007944">

      DIV CONTENT GOES HERE!

  </div>
</div>
```

Also `contents` should be a list of div tags, so lets access the first element of the list with `[0]`

So try this one.

```py
contents = bs.find_all('div', {'class':'result_list'})
# contents is now a list of divs
sight_item = contents[0].div.div
data_address = sight_item['data-address']
print(data_address)


# output
# 广州市番禺区大石镇105国道大石段593号

data_point = sight_item['data-point']
print(data_point)

#output
# 113.321711,23.007944
```