# Extracting values from HTML attributes with Soup

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup, extract

[This is](https://pastebin.com/yyMjmCYj) a complete html I work with.

This is simplified version of above HTML:

```
<table class="premium">
    <tr class="retailer top-offer" data-pricer="47.84" saler-id="123">...</td>
    <tr class="retailer" data-pricer="57.11" saler-id="234">...</td>
</table>
<table class="basic-supp">
    <tr class="retailer top-offer" data-pricer="41.87" saler-id="456">...</td>
    <tr class="retailer" data-pricer="58.12" saler-id="567">...</td>
</table>
```

From TABLE with *class="basic-supp"* from *TR* tags and from *data-pricer="..."* attributes I need to extract values.

I tried this method on simplified html:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
with open('file.html', 'r') as f:
    contents = f.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'lxml')
tags = soup.find_all('tr')
for tag in tags:
    print(tag.attrs['data-pricer'])

> 47.84
> 57.11
> 41.87
> 58.12
```

This is almost what I need, except the fact it takes values from both tables instead the table with *class="basic-supp"*. Any idea how to fix it?

And the main problem is it doesn't work at all on complete html I posted above. The error:

```
    print(tag.attrs['data-pricer'])
KeyError: 'data-pricer'
```

Can somebody give me advice please?

Thank you for your time!

P.S. This is not even close duplicate of post [Extracting an attribute value with beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612548/extracting-an-attribute-value-with-beautifulsoup)

Comment: Duplicate [How to find elements by class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041008/how-to-find-elements-by-class)

Comment: No it doesn't. Have you actually read my question?

Answer (score 1):

First find `<tr>` then with `tr['data-pricer']` get what you want.

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<table class="premium">
    <tr class="retailer top-offer" data-pricer="47.84" saler-id="123">...</td>
    <tr class="retailer" data-pricer="57.11" saler-id="234">...</td>
</table>
<table class="basic-supp">
    <tr class="retailer top-offer" data-pricer="41.87" saler-id="456">...</td>
    <tr class="retailer" data-pricer="58.12" saler-id="567">...</td>
</table>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html , 'html.parser')
for table in soup.find_all("table", {"class": "basic-supp"}):
    for tr in table.find_all('tr'):
        print(tr['data-pricer'])
```

Comment: I am not sure what is difference. This gives me values from both tables again.

Comment: @neznajut edited my answer, is this correct?

Comment: This is nice! Thank you! But this is half solution.

Tt still don't work on [complete html I work with](https://pastebin.com/yyMjmCYj). Maybe you can see where is the problem.

Comment: On complete version of my html are little bit different names of classes.
Instead class="supplier" is class=". . . table-basic-supplier".
Instead class="data-pricer" is class="data-priceek".

I am trying to edit the code you offered, but it won't work.

`soup = BeautifulSoup(html , 'html.parser')
for table in soup.find_all("table", {"class": "table-basic-supplier"}):
    for tr in table.find_all('tr'):
        print(tr['data-priceek'])`

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to just use css selectors:

```
data = []
for tr in soup.select('table.basic-supp tr'):
    data.append([tr['data-pricer'],tr['saler-id'] ])
print(data)
```

Or, if you want to use extreme list comprehensions, a one liner:

```
[[tr['data-pricer'],tr['saler-id']] for tr in soup.select('table.basic-supp tr')]
```

In either case, the output should be:

```
[['41.87', '456'], ['58.12', '567']]
```

Comment: It still doesn't work on complete html code I have. https://pastebin.com/yyMjmCYj

There are bit different names of classes. Instead class="supplier" is class=". . . table-basic-supplier". Instead class="data-pricer" is class="data-priceek".
Tried to change your code consider new classes names but it doesn't work.