# How do I get href value instead of the text from a result set?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, resultset

I'm using

`print(d.contents)`

My print loop prints the following `ResultSets`:

```
[<a href="Property.aspx?pi=cd1a0b90-07aa-ec11-aa4c-246e960cbc4d" title="3 Bedroom House For Sale In Anthoupoli, Nicosia">3 Bedroom House For Sale In Anthoupoli, Nicosia</a>]
[<a href="Property.aspx?pi=c42dc379-5f67-e811-bb4e-a4badb3ceace" title="2 Storey Modern 3 Bedroom House For Sale In Dali Area">2 Storey Modern 3 Bedroom House For Sale In Dali Area</a>]
[<a href="Property.aspx?pi=6370763d-61ab-e811-b319-a4badb3ceacd" title="Very Nice And Spacious 3 Bedroom Detached House For Sale In Lakatamia">Very Nice And Spacious 3 Bedroom Detached House For Sale In Lakatamia</a>]
[<a href="Property.aspx?pi=7da50193-266b-e811-bb4e-a4badb3ceace" title="3 Bedroom Under Construction Detached 4 Houses For Sale In Tseri Area">3 Bedroom Under Construction Detached 4 Houses For Sale In Tseri Area</a>]
[<a href="Property.aspx?pi=96d0fb0a-89bd-ec11-aa4e-246e960cbc4d" title="3 Bedroom House For Sale In Agios Dometios, Nicosia">3 Bedroom House For Sale In Agios Dometios, Nicosia</a>]
[<a href="Property.aspx?pi=1881b78e-52d7-ec11-aa4e-246e960cbc4d" title="4 Bedroom House For Sale In Archangelos, Nicosia">4 Bedroom House For Sale In Archangelos, Nicosia</a>]
[<a href="Property.aspx?pi=eaa2b630-e685-ec11-aa4c-246e960cbc4d" title="In Excellent Location 3 Bedrooms House In Archangelos Nicosia">In Excellent Location 3 Bedrooms House In Archangelos Nicosia</a>]
[<a href="Property.aspx?pi=2ad40da2-a190-ec11-aa4c-246e960cbc4d" title="Incomplete residential development in Politiko, Nicosia">Incomplete residential development in Politiko, Nicosia</a>]
[<a href="Property.aspx?pi=a19ad42e-cd59-e911-8b16-a4badb3ceacd" title="3 Bedroom House For Sale In Spilia With Great View">3 Bedroom House For Sale In Spilia With Great View</a>]
```

How can I print only the values of `href` attribute?

I noticed that using
`print(d.text)` gives me only the titles, but I want the URLs instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extracting an attribute value with beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612548/extracting-an-attribute-value-with-beautifulsoup)

Comment: @buran Not really

Comment: You want to get the `href` attribute of an `a` tag, right?

Comment: And, please, edit your question to include [mre].

Comment: @buran Yeah but what I have is resultsets (list) and I can't use beautifulsoup's attribute selector with lists. I get "list indices must be integers or slices, not str" when I try to use print(d.find_all('a')['href']). Only print(d.contents) and print(d.text) works and it's not giving me what I want.

Comment: you get lists with one element because you use `find_all`. Use `find`, or acces element of a list by index.

Comment: @buran You are right, thanks. But now I'm stuck, how do I iteratively print every element of the list? I tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of [`d.contents`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children) that will always create a `ResultSet` of elements children, select the one and only `<a>` in your element directly and extract its `href`:

```
d.a.get('href')
```

or

```
d.find('a').get('href')
```

---

In addition you could also select your elements more specific

```
for e in soup.select('#properties h3 a'):
    print(e.get('href'))
```

##### Example

For your next question try to create an [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) like this, to make it easier for others to understand the situation and your issue.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<div id="properties">

<div class="item">
    <div class="item-header clearfix">
        <h3><a href="Property.aspx?pi=92700a36-fd11-ec11-aa4a-246e960cbc4d" title="3 Bedroom House For Sale In Akaki">3 Bedroom House For Sale In Akaki</a></h3>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <div class="item-header clearfix">
        <h3><a href="Property.aspx?pi=dc3f03fe-6140-ea11-a1df-a4badb3ceacd" title="Shop For Sale in Nicosia Center">Shop For Sale in Nicosia Center</a></h3>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <div class="item-header clearfix">
        <h3><a href="Property.aspx?pi=7f72737d-72e2-ec11-aa4e-246e960cbc4d" title="1 Bedroom Apartment For Sale In Strovolos, Nicosia">1 Bedroom Apartment For Sale In Strovolos, Nicosia</a></h3>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for e in soup.select('#properties h3 a'):
    print(e.get('href'))
```

##### Output

```
Property.aspx?pi=92700a36-fd11-ec11-aa4a-246e960cbc4d
Property.aspx?pi=dc3f03fe-6140-ea11-a1df-a4badb3ceacd
Property.aspx?pi=7f72737d-72e2-ec11-aa4e-246e960cbc4d
```